# Android database working with currency/balance

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am developing an app that manages users expenses and incomes, I have reached a point where I am pretty stuck and feel like I need some help, What I want to do is save have a record of the total user balance and to be able to do calculations on it, depending on the users actions, If hes balance is 100 dollars and he adds an expense of 50 dollars, the saved balance will be updated to total of 50 dollars etc..

I am not sure what is the right way to do it or how to write the database function to do the math on the "balance" variable, this is my database class so far, I would really appreciate any example or tip.

Right now all I am having is the basic "add,update,remove,fetch" functions...

```
public class TransactionsDatabase {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "transactions_db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "transactions_table";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TRANSACTION_ID = "_id";
private static final String TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TRANSACTION_DATE = "date";
private static final String TRANSACTION_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String TRANSACTION_CURRENCY = "currency_type";
private static final String TRANSACTION_EXPENSE_OR_INCOME = "expenseOrIncome";
private static int BALANCE; // this is how I have tried to use the balance so far...

private static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "create table transactions_table (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ "amount integer not null, date text not null, category text not null, currency_type text not null, description text not null, expenseOrIncome text not null);";

private static final String TAG = "TransactionsDatabase";
private DatabaseHelper DbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase SqlDatabase;
private final Context ctx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will erase old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses_table");
        onCreate(db);
    }       
}

TransactionsDatabase (Context c) {
    this.ctx = c;
}

public TransactionsDatabase open() throws SQLException {

    DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    SqlDatabase = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {

    DbHelper.close();
}

public long createExpenseOrIncome (int amount, String description, String date, String category, String currency_type, String expenseOrIncome) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, amount);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_DATE, date);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_CURRENCY, currency_type);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_EXPENSE_OR_INCOME, expenseOrIncome);

    // Returns the row ID of newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.
    return SqlDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}

public boolean deleteExpenseOrIncome(long rowId) {

    // Returns true if deleted, false otherwise.
    return SqlDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, TRANSACTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

}

public Cursor fetchAllExpensesAndIncomes() {

    // Returns a cursor over the list of all expenses/incomes.

    return SqlDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { TRANSACTION_ID,
            TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION, TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_CATEGORY, TRANSACTION_CURRENCY, TRANSACTION_EXPENSE_OR_INCOME }, null, null, null, null,
            null);
}

public Cursor fetchSpecificExpenseOrIncome(long rowId) throws SQLException  {

        Cursor mCursor = SqlDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { 
                TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION, 
                TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_CATEGORY, TRANSACTION_CURRENCY, TRANSACTION_EXPENSE_OR_INCOME },
                TRANSACTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
            return mCursor;
    }

public boolean updateExpenseOrIncome(long rowId, int amount, String description, String date, String category, String currency_type, String expenseOrIncome) {

    // returns true if the expense/income was successfully updated, false otherwise.

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, amount);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_DATE, date);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_CURRENCY, currency_type);
    values.put(TRANSACTION_EXPENSE_OR_INCOME, expenseOrIncome);

    return SqlDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, TRANSACTION_ID + "=" + rowId,  null) > 0;

}

public boolean deleteAllExpensesOrIncomes() {

    // true if any number of rows were deleted, false otherwise.

    return SqlDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null) > 0;
}

public boolean deleteSpecificExpenseOrIncome(long rowId) {

    // true if a row is deleted, false otherwise.

    return SqlDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, TRANSACTION_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is just a single-user android application, I'm going to skip the bit about caching calculated values (because an SQLite lookup is not very time-consuming). If you think you need that extra bit of performance, though, you should definitely consider having a second table to cache calculated values that is updated when you re-run your calculations.

Now then, on to your real question:

Let's say that you want to write a basic function to get the total balance based on your transactions and some base value. It might look a bit like this:

```
public int getBalance(int baseValue) {
    String[] cols = new String[] {
        "SUM(" + TRANSACTION_AMOUNT + ")"
    };
    try {
        Cursor data = SqlDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
        return data.getInt(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(cols[0])) + baseValue;
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", "Couldn't get balance", e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The [`SUM(..)`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) SQL function returns the sum of the values of the column.

Of course, this code won't work right away because, for one thing, you've got a separate `expenseOrIncome` column. There are a couple of ways to deal with that. Firstly: you could rewrite things to use only one column and have negative values be treated as expenses and positive values treated as income.

Alternatively, you could perform two queries. The first would select your income and the second your expenses. Then you'd subtract the expenses from the income to obtain your balance.

Comment: Thank you for you're response, I am glad someone could point me into the right direction, Now about the expenseOrIncome, I am using a radioGroup of 2 choices to determine which is it an expense or income entry, I would be happy if you could help me implement you're suggestion to use 1 colum for both.

Comment: When you save the data from your input fragment/activity, do something like the following: `boolean isExpense = /*code to get whether it is an expense or income */; int amount = /* code to get the transaction amount */; if(isExpense) { amount *= -1; }` This flips the sign of the transaction amount such that if it is an expense, it will be opposite of what was entered. Assuming that your users enter valid data, this will always end up being positive for income and negative for expenses. Then, you'd just store this value in your TRANSACTION_AMOUNT column.

Comment: Perfect! this way I dont even need the expenseOrIncome column!.. oh but if I give up this column How will I keep track of history log? like all the expenses and incomes the user inserted before? I mean there has to be a way to save each transaction and keep track what each transaction was.

Comment: Just check whether the value of the transaction is above or below zero. If above zero, it's an expense. The SQL would look something like `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transaction_amount < 0;` for expenses, for example.